# RC filter impulse response is exponential decaying but inverse Fourier is Sinc function

Tags: low-pass, fourier, frequency-response, digital-filter, step-response

As we all know that the inverse Fourier transform of a frequency domain unit pulse/rectangular function (which looks like low pass filter) is Sinc function. So, I was under the impression that any low pass filter impulse response would look like Sinc function.

[image]

However, the RC low pass filters impulse response look like an exponentially decaying function.

[image]

Since both are low pass filters with the similar looking frequency domain transfer functions, why RC low pass filter response does not look like Sinc function?

Comment: No, sinc function in the time domain only applies to rectangular frequency response (and vice versa). A first order (RC) LPF does have a decaying exponential. And there are other characteristics : uniquely, a Gaussian LPF has a Gaussian time domain response... There used to be a time when math courses taught the commonest Laplace transforms like these.

Comment: Is a rectangular pulse the same as an exponentially decaying waveform? Not only they are not, but one is symmetric, the other is not. According to your logic -- "*Since both are low pass filters with the similar looking frequency domain transfer functions*" -- a Bessel lowpass is the same as an elliptic/Cauer lowpass. The transfer functions are really not the same.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the short answer: a first-order lowpass and a rectangular-in-frequency filter *don't* look the same in the frequency domain.  So why should they be the same when you take the inverse Fourier transform?

[image]

Comment: SINC pulses do not need to be square. e.g. Blackman, Welsh etc

Comment: There is exactly one sinc function, and its Fourier transform is square.  There may be functions *like* the sinc function -- but their Fourier transforms are going to be way more square than \$1/(\tau s + 1)\$.  So I think my point stands.

Comment: You think only square windows make SINC functions.? https://fiiir.com/

Comment: [By definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) \$\mathrm{sinc} x = \lim_{\chi \to x} \frac{\sin \pi \chi}{\pi \chi}\$.  That page you reference is generating what it calls "windowed sinc".  **Not** plain ol' sinc.

Comment: So in theoretical terms, it must be a "boxcar" but in practical terms it doesn't.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that your sinc-like filter is called "sinc" anywhere else but that page, and that a preponderance of DSP folks would see a frequency-domain plot of a windowed sinc filter and say "oh, yes, that's the frequency response of a sinc filter".  Because in practical terms, if you use a term that no one else does and everyone gets confused, you're not being practical.